# What is this css rule -ms-high-contrast-adjust?

Tags: html, css

While viewing Facebook source, I came across this property. Google yeilded no results.

```
i.img {
    -ms-high-contrast-adjust: none;
    _overflow: hidden;
}
```

Apparently, chrome inspector doesn't recognize it.

[image: Chrome Inspector]

Comment: Which property? There are two there.

Comment: The reason chrome inspector crosses it out could also be because its get overruled at some point

Comment: @Taacoo — No. It is crossed out because it is invalid.

Comment: First page on google : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441137.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20013725/2887133 .. more info about it

Comment: @DaniP: thanks. it was informative. :)

Comment: The statement that Chrome inspector doesn't *"recognize"* it **is not true**. Inspector recognizes it (that's why you see it listed). The *strike-through* means it **does not apply** for one of the following reasons: **a)** the "key-value" pair is *invalid*. **b)** the property value is overridden by a rule with a stronger selector. In this case, we're looking at **a)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs for `-ms-high-contrast-adjust` can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771863(v=vs.85).aspx

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to override any Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) properties that would have been set in high contrast mode.
>
> **auto** Indicates the applicable CSS properties will be adjusted as expected when the system is in high contrast mode.
>
> **none** Indicates the applicable CSS properties will not be adjusted when the system is in high contrast mode.

More info on the underscore prefix can be found in this post: [Does the minus sign or underscore in css do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521312/does-the-minus-sign-or-underscore-in-css-do-anything)

And this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack

> Versions 6 and below of Internet Explorer recognized properties with this prefix (after discarding the prefix). All other browsers ignore such properties as invalid. Therefore, a property that is preceded by an underscore or a hyphen was applied exclusively in Internet Explorer 6 and below.

Edit: When using a search engine, wrap your CSS rule in quotes to have the results you want pop up. For example: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css+%22-ms-high-contrast-adjust%22

Answer (score 7):

The *Chrome* inspector won't apply the `-ms-high-contrast-adjust` property because it is using the Microsoft-specific vendor prefix: `-ms`

Underscoring a property, such as `_overflow`, is an [old IE hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack).

So neither will be applied by *Chrome*.

**As for *what* -ms-high-contrast-adjust does:**

> `-ms-high-contrast-adjust` property Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to override any Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) properties that
>   would have been set in high contrast mode.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441137.aspx

(Thanks to Tom C. for the source.)

Comment: The documentation for this property can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh441137.aspx It essentially tells the browser whether it should adjust the element if the user is in high contrast mode.

Comment: What explains why Chrome doesn't recognise it. It doesn't answer the question by explaining what it means.

Comment: FYI: It probably yielded no Google results because of the leading minus ("-") sign in "-ms-high-contrast-adjust". If you remove the leading minus sign, you get lots of results. e.g. "ms-high-contrast-adjust" :)

Comment: @scarabaeus: duh. thats why it yeilded no result :)

Comment: Could you please change **recognize** for **apply**? They are two quite different things, and the first one is simply not true. Chrome recognizes `-ms-...` properties (and therefore lists them in the CSS attributes list). But it does not apply any of them.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the answer has been updated with your suggestion. Thanks!